# How can I import Audio into My Create-React-App application?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, create-react-app

I am building a music-player application, where basically the user clicks the song they want and it plays the assigned music. However I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/MusicPlayer.js 7:0-17

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './music' in '/Users/zpotatlises/Desktop/spotifly/src/components'
```

I am assuming I am getting this error because i imported the audio incorrectly in my application. This image shows the audio folder in my src file.
[image]

(when you open the file) ->
[image]

This is my code on **MusicPlayer.js**:

```
import React, { Component,audio,useRef } from 'react';
import "./music";

import house1 from './music/house1';
import house2 from './music/house2';
import house3 from './music/house3';
import house4 from './music/house4';

const data = [
    { imgSrc: 'house1.png', audioSrc: house1 },
    { imgSrc: 'house2.png', audioSrc: house2 },
    { imgSrc: 'house3.png', audioSrc: house3 },
    { imgSrc: 'house4.png', audioSrc: house4 },
  ];

  export default class MusicPlayer extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ol>
            {data.map(({ imgSrc, audioSrc }) => (
              <MediaComponent imgSrc={imgSrc} audioSrc={audioSrc} />
            ))}
          </ol>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  const MediaComponent = ({ imgSrc, audioSrc }) => {
    const audioRef = useRef(null);
    const toggleAudio = () =>
      audio.ref.current.paused
        ? audioRef.current.play()
        : audioRef.current.pause();
    return (
      <li>
        <img src={imgSrc} onClick={toggleAudio}/>
        <audio ref={audioRef} src={audioSrc} />
      </li>
    );
  };
```

Any idea on how to import audio in my application? How did I do it incorrectly?

(P.s english is my second language, if you need any clarification please let me know)

Best,
-Zpo

**Package.json** :

```
{
  "name": "spotifly",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "navbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.3",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-is": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

New Error Messages:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/MusicPlayer.js 7:0-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './music/house1.mp3' in '/Users/zpotatlises/Desktop/spotifly/src/components'
```

```
ERROR in ./src/components/MusicPlayer.js 8:0-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/music/house2.mp3' in '/Users/zpotatlises/Desktop/spotifly/src/components'
```

```
ERROR in ./src/components/MusicPlayer.js 9:0-48

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../../assets/house3.mp3 which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

Comment: What you've got is correct, so it's most likely just an incorrect relative file path

Comment: what would be the correct file path?

Comment: Ha ha, well I couldn't tell you without seeing your file structure. But using relative paths (`../` or `../../../` type thing) gets confusing and can lead to errors, so consider setting up aliases (like `@/assets/my-tune.mp3`)

Comment: This is the file path when i try to import it, looks like it works registers. This is what you're talking about correct? I added picture above

Comment: Can you share what your directory structure looks like? IntelliSense doesn't always work the same as webpack. Is your music file inside your `components` directory? Because that's where it's looking for it.

Comment: I believe so ,Yes it is in the components directory, (new image above)

Comment: Also, just noticed that you're missing the file extension which you should need for assets, update it to `import house1 from './music/house1.mp3';`. And then remove `import "./music";`

Comment: I moved my music folder from components folder, to the src folder. I have two questionss: 1.) I updated my code to show my package.json folder, please show where to put “{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
“ in inside the file. 2.) Can you show the correct import strategy with my code? i tried doing “../../../assets/my-tune.mp3” or “@/assets/my-tune.mp3 “ and it did not work. Pretty sure i’ve misunderstood some of your advice .Thank you for your patience really appreciate it!

Comment: Those were just examples, obviously you will need to use your correct file names and paths....

Comment: Yes haha that was a typo, I meant to say that i tried doing it like “../../../music/house1.mp3” and “@/music/house1.mp3 “. I still received an error.

Comment: Your error message must have changes now that you've removed `import "./music";`. What's your new error message?

Comment: I tried importing the music three ways to see what works, one is import house1 from './music/house1.mp3';. 2nd way) import house2 from '@/music/house2.mp3'; 3rd way)import house3 from '../../../assets/house3.mp3';.I pasted there error messages above.

Comment: Another side note, the music folder is in the src folder. I moved it out of the components folder.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of, is that you need to configure mp3 file types within your loader. If it was webpack, it would look something liks: `{ test: /\.mp3$/, loader: 'file', query: { name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]' } }`.

Comment: Okay, if you moved it out of the components folder, you need to update your import statements, because those error messages clearly show they're still looking in the components directory. I feel like we're going round in circles now. You should research file imports, and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, so you've likely got the path wrong.

Be sure to include the file's extension for media assets (`.mp3`)

Based on your error message, it is looking for `./music` inside your `components` directory, which likely isn't correct.

Delete `import "./music";` and then import the specific MP3 files you need

```
Can't resolve './music' in '/Users/zpotatlises/Desktop/spotifly/src/components'
```

Take a look at where your asset is in relation to the file that's importing it. If you're able to share more info about your projects directory structure, then I can help further.

---

Side note, I recommend setting up import aliases, so that you can import files from their absolute location. It will reduce confusion and be easier to manage.

How you do this depends on your type of project, but it's usually something like thin in your tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

You'll then be able to import `@/assets/my-tune.mp3` instead of `../../../assets/my-tune.mp3`, much simpler :)

Comment: Would you recommend adding the music in an assets folder, rather than a music folder?

Comment: It doesn't matter what it's called, but you probably don't want it inside your `components` directory

Answer (score 1):

[image: 1]

Usage:
Just create a file index.js in videos.

```
import videos from '~/assets/videos';

function App() {
 return <video src={videos.video1} width={100} height={100} controls autoPlay/>
}
```